# Wordpress - Error establishing a database connection - Am I hacked?

Tags: wordpress

Two days after launching my wordpress blog, suddenly all its pages started to refresh themselves automatically even before loading anything. Five hours later I got this message

```
Error establishing a database connection
```

Is my blog hacked or what?

Comment: You should deactivate all the plugins to see if the site is ok or not, also turn WP_DEBUG to true and watch your error log.

Comment: check your database connection , wp-config.php file

Answer (score 0):

May be some DDOS attack.
Check your CPU usage, may be MySQL crashed due to excessive load because all RAM is used up serving the requests.

Check apache access_log to see are there any bots continuously hitting your site, also deactivate your xmlrpc.php.